# Struct with field holding a mutable reference to another instance of this same struct

Tags: rust

I have a struct which has a field (named `outer`) that I would like to hold a mutable reference to another instance of this same struct. I want to specify to the compiler that this `outer` field will always live for at least as long as the current instance.

A simplified version of the issue (that does not compile yet):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Env<'a> {
    symbols: HashMap<String, i64>,
    outer: Option<&'a mut Env<'a>>
}

impl <'a> Env<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Env {
            symbols: HashMap::new(),
            outer: None,
        }
    }

    fn new_enclosed(outer: &'a mut Env<'a>) -> Self {
        Env {
            symbols: HashMap::new(),
            outer: Some(outer),
        }
    }

    fn resolve(&self, name: &str) -> i64 {
        if self.symbols.contains_key(name) {
            return *self.symbols.get(name).unwrap();
        }

        if let Some(outer) = &self.outer {
            return outer.resolve(name);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, name: &str, value: i64) {
        self.symbols.insert(name.to_owned(), value);
    }

    fn update(&mut self, name: &str, value: i64) {
        if self.symbols.contains_key(name) {
            self.symbols.insert(name.to_owned(), value);
        } else {
            if let Some(outer) = &mut self.outer {
                return outer.update(name, value);
            }
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    // outer env
    let mut env = Env::new(); 
    env.insert("foo", 0);
    env.insert("bar", 0);

    one(&mut env);

    assert_eq!(env.resolve("foo"), 0); // <-- Cannot borrow as mutable more than once.
    assert_eq!(env.resolve("bar"), 2); // <-- Cannot borrow as mutable more than once.
}

fn one<'a>(outer: &'a mut Env<'a>) {
    let mut env = Env::new_enclosed(outer);
    env.insert("foo", 1);
    env.update("bar", 1);

    for i in 1..3 {
        two(&mut env); // <-- Cannot borrow as mutable more than once.
    }
}


fn two<'b>(outer: &'b mut Env<'b>) {
    let mut env = Env::new_enclosed(outer);
    env.insert("foo", 2);
    env.update("bar", 2);
}
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0836f29242e6683a15b57d829657306b

In theory, this sort of structure should be possible without wrapping `Env` in `<Rc<RefCell<...>>`, right? So I'm guessing I am messing up the lifetime parameters for the functions `one` and `two` in this example, but can't seem to figure it out.

Any pointers (pun intended) would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**:

So now I don't think this sort of setup is possible without `RefCell` because I am passing the mutable reference inside a loop, which is never possible (right?). So there probably isn't an easy answer to this besides a completely different structure altogether, which I would still be very interested to hear other people's thoughts on. But also maybe I should not be afraid to use RefCell at all?

For example, are there any runtime costs associated with RefCell when simply using it to borrow a non-mutable reference?

Comment: Here's a working example of what I intend the code to do (using RefCell), but ideally I would like the borrowing rules to be checked at compile time vs. at runtime.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=321d4ec562d79f23040effd26bbe0e7f

Comment: I think that, essentially, the problem is that `&'a mut Env<'a>` ties the lifetime of the reference to the parent environment to the lifetime of the reference within the parent environment. I'm not sure how to decouple them, though.